# ASP.NET 'FindByNameAsync' returns null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm having an issue with the `ForgotPassword` method for the base asp.net identity. When stepping through the code, the line `var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);` returns `null`, even though I have confirmed that the email address for the user exists in the `aspnetusers` table. I'm not sure why Visual Studio will not allow me to step into the `FindByNameAsync` method? Not sure what's going on here?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", 
        new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
        "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");        
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: according to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613101(v=vs.108).aspx) that method takes a username. I'm not sure if your usernames are the same as email addresses, but that is usually not the case. Maybe try a different field from the model that is the user id that FindByNameAsync expects or use FIndbyEmailAsync?

Comment: you have to use this method var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email); because your parameter is email.

Comment: I can't believe that I missed that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to find an user by an email address.

You should use [UserManager.FindByEmailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151641(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.FindByEmailAsync(System.String))

Comment: The above works but I'm having this problem as well when trying to log in which is problem as only FindByName has both the username and password so using this method is no good. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I found a workaround using your suggestion to return the user and then use UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password).

Answer (score 10):

This usually happens when you create the user using some other method than **CreateAsync** in **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager**. I had the same issue because I was creating the users directly through EF, not the referred method.

All FindBy methods should work properly using this approach.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue for the project based on ASP.NET Core 2.2. Maybe my solution will be useful for someone.

The user can change their `UserName` in the UserProfile component (by default, the `UserName` was the same as Email, i.e., `user1@mail.com`). If the user changed their Username in the profile from the default `user1@mail.com` to `user1`, then they could not log in using this new UserName, only Email.

The line below always returned NULL.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
```

After investigating the AspCore repository, I found [FindByNameAsync method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/605c522fa3e875fd6d3aefa783a71d1745b7e4c7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L545). I become suspicious about `NormalizeName` line. And my current model for the `UserProfile` model had only `UserName` property, which was mapped later using **Automapper** and saved to the database. So I added computed `NormalizedUserName` property and also mapped it with **Automapper** (`_mapper.Map(UserProfileModel, dbUser);`) and saved it to the database.

```
        public string NormalizedUserName
        {
            get
            {
                return UserName.ToUpper().Normalize(); // `UserManager` UserFindByNameAsync method is using `normalizedName` = `NormalizedUserName` from Users table (for some reason UPPERCASE, maybe SQL performance), otherwise we will always get NULL
            }
        }
```

Changes mentioned above solved my issue for NULL when using the `FindByNameAsync` method.

Comment: I faced this problem NormalizedUsername is different username in my db. Someone updated table manually. Thanks you ))

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the User table has a [Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) applied to it and the filter criteria is not met.